# Delete row based on it's position in table

Tags: mysql

Let us presume that we have a table which's rows are identified only by their position, and have no other particular differences (as a primary key, an id, a timestamp, etc) and 
as MySQL 'DELETE' syntax does not allow LIMIT how does one succeed in deleting a row in such a table.

Like:

```
DELETE FROM `table` LIMIT 49,1
```

As it is possible to:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 49,1
```

I thank you  in advance for your kindness to help with an answer.

Comment: Normally, you would need to add an additional column to store the row position. With the position, then you can easily delete row with position 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a useful feature, because the order of rows in the table is not guaranteed. Under load, a table will invariably come out in a different order due to the behaviour of MySQL.

You might try the following but as stated above, it's not guaranteed to be accurate

```
DELETE FROM `table` 
     WHERE `col1` IN (SELECT `col1` FROM `table` LIMIT 49,1) 
        AND `col2` IN (SELECT `col2` FROM `table` LIMIT 49,1) 
        AND ...
     LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: What if I have 2 rows with exactly the same information stored? Is there a solution for it?

Comment: That's the purpose of LIMIT 1

Comment: So it will take only the first one?... Isn't there any other way? Let's say I want to delete the third such row. I know it might not matter it's position among others with identical information, but this is how I identify any row in one go, as elements of an array.

Comment: @khael, you should really reconsider your database design

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard it is not the database but the way I work with it, even if I can rely on a good architecture the piece of code I am working on must be used with any kind of tables, even if they aren't mine, and I want see it work in any circumstances.

Comment: Maybe this answer is the best, if none other will ever show up :(, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Tables are sets; the rows do not have positions.

Comment: Even considering this, there is a reading order, I want to use, I can organize my operations by it.